# Копирующая, прямая и uniform-инициализация в C++

Tags: c++

Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее про разные виды инциализации и когда именно какую из них лучше применять? И для чего именно была создана uniform-инициализация? Я правильно понимаю, что для того, чтобы иметь возможность все объекты инциализировать единообразно, будь то обычная переменная фундаментального типа или std::vector? Насколько я понимаю, нет никакой разницы между, например, следующими примерами инициализаций.

### Копирующая инициализация:

```
    int var = 2022;
```

### Прямая инициализация:

```
    int var (2022);
```

### Uniform-инициализация:

```
    int var {2022};
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что помимо того, что uniform-инициализация работает для всех объектов, у неё ещё есть дополнительное преимущество, заключающееся в том, что она безопаснее? То есть нельзя присвоить объекту то значение, которое его тип не поддерживает (компилятор выдаст ошибку).

```
    int var {2022.5}; // ошибка
```

Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее про инициализацию.

Comment: Я думаю, вам сейчас тут много всего расскажут, но imho все эти новшества -- [очередной крестовый бред](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/) от людей, положивших на KISS и забывших о бритве Оккама

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Comment: вот что Страуструп об этом думает: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-list